# How to manage a stream of 3,000 telemetry sensor data points per second?

Tags: c++, streaming, accelerometer, sensors, robotics

I am working on a robotics project which streams about 3,000 data points/s of sensor data over wifi.

Once this data arrives it needs to be accessed by two applications.

I am confused as to how to manage this data, one option which came to mind is an in-memory database. This would allow the applications to connect to the database and access the data.

Are there any frameworks built to handle such workloads and if not what is the best way to manage such data?

Preferably the streaming data is stored on disk for debugging however this is not essential.

Comment: How much latency between points being received and being processed can your system tolerate?

Comment: Up to 400-500ms between receiving the data and having it available for the next process is okay. Ideally less then that if possible.